# MODIS(MYD06_L2) file concatenation using xarray and dask

Tags: concatenation, dask, python-xarray, dask-delayed

I try to open multiple MODIS files (MYD06_L2) using `xarray (xr.open_mfdataset)`.

I can open a single file or may be some files but i am not able to open many files or one day file as they have different dimensions.

```
d06 = xr.open_mfdataset(M06_2040, concat_dim= 'None', parallel=True)
['Cloud_Mask_1km'][:,:,:,0].values
```

Here `M06_2040` is the directory of the files

I end up with the following error:

> ValueError: arguments without labels along dimension
>   'Cell_Along_Swath_1km:mod06' cannot be aligned because they have
>   different dimension sizes: {2040, 2030}

Comment: I dealt with the same thing parsing MODIS data and the two different swath sizes. My workaround was to get a list of all files with swath size 2030 and 2040 and load each list separately with open_mfdataset.

Comment: Did you get any ways to fix this issue in concat dims?

Answer (score 2):

Correct.  I believe that the `xarray.open_mfdataset` function expects that all dimensions other than the concatenated dimension are the same in all files.